# Array Formula through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write an array formula via VBA but getting an error " unable to set the FormulaArray property of the range class". I have tried both ' Range.FormulaArray' and '.Range.selection.FormulaArray' but nothing works. Thanks for helping me with this.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Table2[[" & Me.cboSec.value & " Row Score Max]]").FormulaArray = formulae
```

Comment: How long is the formula? If it's over 255 characters you will get that error.

Comment: Is it really `sheet1` or is it `Sheet1`?

Comment: @Rory, the formula is less than 255 characters.

Comment: @Tannman357, The worksheet name is in small letters.

Comment: Okay just wanted to check - I've made many mistakes like that before.

Comment: Just noticed it's a table - you can't use a multi-cell array formula in a table. You should only enter the array formula into the first cell: `Worksheets("sheet1").Listobjects("Table2").Listcolumns(Me.cboSec.value & " Row Score Max").DataBodyRange.cells(1).FormulaArray = formulae`

Comment: Thx Rory, your code works. But one question how do I make sure that the Array Formula is copied in my entire column of the table? Should I do a loop: DataBodyRange.cells(i)??

Comment: Maybe I can help, I've edited my answer. Thank you Rory and Ron Rosenfeld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minimal snippet works for me:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B4").FormulaArray = "=AVERAGE(C1:C5)"
```

This will have the cells from A1 to B4 showing the average of the numbers in cells C1 to C5, and being bound to a formula array.

But the question mentions structured references to a Table. As Rory mentioned, in a Table are no formula arrays possible. You can dig to the ground if you try to insert an array into the Table manually by `<CTRL><SHIFT><ENTER>`, which is the usual not programmatic way. Excel answers with: "Multi-cell array formulas are not allowed in tables."

But in order to at least fill the cells of a Table with a set of equal formulas, this minimal snippet works for me:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=SUM($F$1:$G$1)"
```

or

```
Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Cells.Formula = "=SUM($F$1:$G$1)"
```

Here is one more inspiring hint: http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-2007-tables

For the Table, recording macros won't help as recording sticks to the lowest complex description necessary.

Comment: .Range("TableauCalcs[[" & Me.cboSectors.value & " Row Score Max]]") seems to be causing the error I guess. This is the header name of one of my table columns and I want to insert the Array Formula in this column.

Comment: Hmmm... what do you mean by "header name"? There are named ranges in Excel and "common" ranges. Both are addressed with this syntax: a) `Sheet1.Range("A1:B5")` -> range, b) `Sheet1.Range("A:A")` -> full column, c) `Sheet1.Range("MyNamedRange")` -> the cells I gave the name "MyNamedRange". So what is the header name?

Comment: Annnnnnnd... I have never seen the notation with brackets. If I should separate a sheet from a range, I use the exclamation mark: `Sheet1.Range("TheOtherSheet!A1:B7")`. What is the bracket notation for?

Comment: I have a Table called TableauCalcs. By header I mean, column header of one of my columns in TableauCalcs.  [" & Me.cboSectors.value & " Row Score Max] is the column header name of my column where I want to insert the Array Formula. By the way the Array Formula is working fine when I insert it manually in my worksheet.

Comment: I have inserted another formula (using .Formula) in the adjacent cell through VBA and it works fine. The formula is

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("TableauCalcs[[" & Me.cboSectors.value & " Count of ?]]").Formula = "=IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(Table1[@[" & Me.Option1.value & "]],0,0,1,nbCol" & Me.cboSectors.value & "),""?""),""ND"")"

Comment: @peter_the_oak The brackets are used for Table references.  Lookup "Structured References" in Excel Help

Comment: @Ron: Today I've learnt sth totally new, so thanks a lot for the link.