# Excel VBA / math: count how many groups of n are in a range of numbers

Tags: excel, math, grouping, equation, vba

I'm having a bit of a brain freeze, I thought this would be simple but it's not coming to me. I need an equation to calculate the number of groups of 10 in a variable range of variable data. Here's a small example, the real thing has hundreds of numbers with a variable min and max:

```
Number      Rounded number to nearest 10
303.9       300
285         290 - min
443         440
446.8       450
461.1       460 - max
428.83      430
428.545     430
445.835     450
427.215     430
429.97      430

Unique groups of 10     
300     
290     
440     
450     
460     
430     

Answer = 6 groups
```

I don't want to use pivot tables or group functions, I'd rather keep it solely in VBA. Also I don't want to work out the rounded values first and then count the distinct ones because I'd like to use the number to dimension an array, which I'll then populate in a loop. Is there a clever bit of math that can give answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any clever math to do this. You could do this with worksheet formulas:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(ROUND(r,dec_places),ROUND(r,dec_places))>0))
```

where `r` is the data range and dec_places is the amount of rounding (since you're rounding to the nearest 10s, dec_places = -1).

You could implement this in VBA with something like:

```
Function CountUniqueRounded(r As Range, dec_places As Double) As Long
    ' Implement this worksheet formula
    '    =SUM(--(FREQUENCY(ROUND(r,dec_places),ROUND(r,dec_places))>0))
    Dim rAddr As String
    Dim rFormula As String
    Dim c As Long

    ' Build up the formula string
    rAddr = r.Parent.Name & "!" & r.Address
    rFormula = "ROUND(" & rAddr & "," & CStr(dec_places) & ")"
    rFormula = "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(" & rFormula & "," & rFormula & ")>0))"
    ' Debug.Print rFormula
    c = Application.Evaluate(rFormula)
    CountUniqueRounded = c
End Function
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Also, I didn't know about application.evaluate so that's a bonus :)

Answer (score 1):

I have an Array Formula solution which does not require VBA. Array Formulas take single function which would normally apply only to a single cell, and perform that function over a range of cells, returning an Array of different results (1 for each cell). That Array of results is then collapsed into a single number to give your answer.

Assuming your data is in column A, and goes for less than 1000 rows, this will work:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH(10*(ROW(A1:A1000)),ROUND(A1:A1000,-1),0)*0+1,0))
```

Note that to confirm an Array Formula, you need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, isntead of just ENTER.

What it does is multiplies 10 by each row from A1 to A1000, and then checks to see if that result can be found when rounding each cell present in A1 to A1000. That is, it checks 10, 20, etc. up to 1000, and tries to find it in a range of your rounded values. Whenever it finds a value, it multiplies the row it was found on by 0, and adds 1. Whenever it doesn't find a value (ie: returns an error), it shows 0. The sum of all matches gives you the number of times each rounded number from 10 - 1000 is found.

Caveat - this will not work if you have numbers > 1000; if such numbers would occur you can easily change all instances of 1,000 to 10,000. Likewise if your data sometimes extends further than row 1000, you will need to increase all instances of 1000 to an appropriate number. If data would vary wildly and you can't estimate size / max limit, then there are ways to automate this, but as the formula is already somewhat complex, I left that as a manual process.

Comment: Good explanation and one for the toolkit, thanks. As far as I know there's no way to use an array formula directly in VBA without setting it as a cell formula?

Comment: I've never done it, but I know you can - see here for starters: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24630187/5090027